# How to Create zip file in PHP using shell command on linux server

Tags: php, linux, compression, zip, shell-exec

this is the command that actually i want to run using PHP in Linux server.
`shell_exec(" zip -r abc.doc xyz.doc > foo.zip ");`

Using this command i script create damanged zip file, so can anyone help me to make it proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect.  Try

```
zip foo abc.doc xyz.doc
```

or

```
zip -r foo abc.dox xyz.doc
```

depending upon whether you intend to replace the existing archive or not.  See `man zip` for more.

Comment: not creating zip file on your suggested syntax, as my format is given it creates zip file but damaged (not opening or collecting files to compress)

Comment: Yes, but it creates a zip file of **0 bytes** in size.  Check!

Comment: exactly, thats the point that i want to discuss, so any way to create proper formated zip file.

Comment: What else was mentioned in the answer above?

Comment: devnull yes you are right, "zip foo abc.doc xyz.doc" this command is working properly if we need to zip files, but when we are compressing a folder we use this command = "zip -r archivefile /home/docs/documents"